# How to redirect my forms after submitting info?

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I finally got my forms information to be sent to my email but i'm still having issues with my forms webpage. When I hit the submit button, the browser doesn't refresh the page but instead, goes to my php.file, in which it displays a black page. I'm trying to re-direct the page back to the form webpage (without using java script).

Here is my code so far including PHP file:

```
 <form method="post" action="PHP_Email_Form.php">
                            <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF; font-size:12px; 
                            font-weight:bold"><label>First Name:
                                <input type="text" name="First Name" size="30" maxlength="30"
                                style="margin-left:27px"  />
                            </label></p>
                            <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF; font-size:12px; 
                            font-weight:bold"><label>Last Name:
                                <input type="text" name="Last Name" size="30" maxlength="30" 
                                style="margin-left:27px"  />
                            </label></p>
                            <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF; font-size:12px; 
                            font-weight:bold"><label>Phone Number:
                                <input type="text" name="Phone Number" size="30" maxlength="10"  
                                style="margin-left:5px" />
                            </label></p>
                            <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF; font-size:12px; 
                            font-weight:bold"><label>Email:
                                <input type="text" name="Email" size="30" maxlength="30"  
                                style="margin-left:59px" />
                            </label></p>
                            <p style="margin-top:19px; margin-left:244px;">
                                <input type="submit" value="submit"  />
                            </p>

                        </form>
```

PHP Document:

```
 <?php
 $to = 'dew02d@yahoo.com';
 $subject = 'test email form';
 $message= '';
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
 {
     $message .= $key . ': ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
 }
 mail($to, $subject, $message);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't outputted anything from your PHP so you can just send a header to redirect.

```
<?php

// ... send email

header('Location: /backToMyForm.html');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php header redirection after you have successfully sent the email:

```
<?php
...
...
mail($to, $subject, $message);

header("Location: successmessage.php"); // Redirect browser

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php